# Prevent lightbox inner div from being closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a simple lightbox which runs when the page is ready.

However, I want to implement a form inside of lightbox so if the user clicks on the darker part (or the close button), the form disappears but if he clicks on any part inside the white one (which wraps the form), it prevents from being closed.

At the moment I have the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // lightbox
  $('.widget').fadeIn(2000);
  $('.lightbox').click(function(e) {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #fff;
}
.lightbox {
  display: table;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(88, 73, 81, 0.85);
}
.widget-wrap {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.widget {
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="widget-wrap">
    <div class="widget">
      <input type="text" placeholder="sample">
      <button>Subscribe</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `return false` from the event handler of the `.widget`. The event will not be bubbled to the parent element i.e. `.lightbox` and lightbox will not be closed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // lightbox
  $('.widget').fadeIn(2000);
  $('.lightbox').click(function(e) {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });

  // For preventing the bubbling of the event to the .widget event handler
  $('.widget').on('click', function() {
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #fff;
}
.lightbox {
  display: table;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(88, 73, 81, 0.85);
}
.widget-wrap {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.widget {
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="widget-wrap">
    <div class="widget">
      <input type="text" placeholder="sample">
      <button>Subscribe</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```